# With and without LINQ - complex sample

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a good and useful code example that would be nice, short and understandable if implemented using LINQ but not so nice and more complex if implemented without LINQ (using loops etc). Maybe something with datetimes and joins.

Anybody know a good example ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best tutorial of LINQ

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b